# How to grade a quiz in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a quiz in javascript html and i am trying to figure out how i would grade it.

here is the html for the quiz:

```
<div id="takeQuiz" class="quiz" style="display:none">
    <p name="questions" class="question" id="q">Random question</p>
    <ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="choices" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="choices" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="choices" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="choices" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

I have created a next() function which creates a new question each time the next question button is clicked.

```
    var next = function () {
    "use strict";
    console.log("next question ");
    var choices;
    choices = document.getElementByName("choices");
    questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    createQuestions();
    //allQuestions += 1;

    if (choices == correct) {
        correct++;
    } 

    if (questionIndex >= 12)
    {
    console.log("the quiz has ended");
    document.getElementById("takeQuiz").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("theQuizResults").style.display = 'block';
    }


};
```

i want to know how to say if the choice selected is the correct one then increase the correct count by 1. So then i can create a gradeQuiz function to grade the quiz once it is complete. I dont even know if im making any sense, any help would be really appreciated

this is a link to the code ive written http://jsfiddle.net/xxsw5u7g/

this is the text file i am loading the questions from into the array

maunga,mountain,ika,fish,awa,river,roto,lake,moana,sea,ngahere,forest,puke,hill,manu,bird,kererū,wood pigeon,kiore,rat,kiwi,kiwi,pīwakawaka,fantail

Comment: Tell us more: where have you stored the correct answers?

Comment: i get the questions from a text file and then put them into an array called allQuestions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xxsw5u7g/  this is the code I have wtitten. in my loaded handler is where i load the file and put it the question and answers into an array.

Comment: @phil - Better to edit the question

Comment: Phil: choices = document.getElementByName("choices"); 
Here, choices contains the DOM element, and not the actual value chosen by the user. You are looking for choices = document.getElementByName("choices").value;

Comment: maunga,mountain,ika,fish,awa,river,roto,lake,moana,sea,ngahere,forest,puke,hill,manu,bird,kerer&#363;,wood pigeon,kiore,rat,kiwi,kiwi,p&#299;wakawaka,fantail   this is the text file i am loading in

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML give same id to all 4 radio buttons.
Keep a hidden variable for storing the count

You can have a submit button and on click call a function name it any thing.

```
function grader()
{
var value=document.getElementbyId('radiobuttonID')
if(value=={original answer})
count++;
}
```